Jquery : Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': missing ) after argument list
I'm trying to upload an image with jquery $.ajax method. I have been using the $.ajax code since many years, but strangely it is not working on this particular project. Here is the code
 <form id="adimgform">
       <input type="file" id="adimage" name="adimage" accept="image/png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/webp" required>
 </form>   

Javascript code
$('#adimage').change(function(){
    uploadimage();
});

function uploadimage()
{
                const adimgform = new FormData($('#adimgform')[0]);
        
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/controller/upload-ad-image.php',
                    type : 'POST',
                    async: true,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: adimgform,
                    enctype: 'multipart/form-data', 
                    success: function (returndata) {            
                    $('#adform1result').html(returndata);    
                    }
                }); 
}

And this is the error im  getting
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': missing ) after argument list
    at m (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:880)
    at $e (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:46274)
    at ce.append (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:47633)
    at ce.<anonymous> (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:48729)
    at M (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:29497)
    at ce.html (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:48405)
    at Object.success (post-now.php?category=1&name=Automobiles:220:41)
    at c (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:25304)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:26053)
    at l (jquery-3.7.1.min.js:2:77782)

strangely, all other forms are working on this site, so im really confused. Any help would be much appreciated, please.

I have this error a lot before.
The error (Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node') indicates a syntax issue, often due to a missing closing parenthesis ), bracket ], or brace } in your code.
The error is being triggered in a script that manipulates the DOM using jQuery.

"The error is being triggered in a script that manipulates the DOM using jQuery.", yes, it seems that the form submission is working, and the response coming from server had some script tags with un closed quotes in a function, thank you
